# In App Purchase Never Completes

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a single user who is experiencing difficulty when making an in app purchase. I've had 60-65 successful in app purchases, but this user has experienced problems a couple times. The in app-purchase is set up as a non-renewing subscription. I believe both times he's had problems he's been trying to make the purchase on the same day his subscription expired. Any idea why his in app purchase process never completes?

Here is how he describes what happens:

Step by step. 
1. Subscription runs out 
2. Click on renew
3. I have password protect on adding apps and paying for apps , so I go thru password and accepting charges. 
4. Charges state accepted in app, however , when I click to use app it continually asks me to renew subscription. (Author note: I think he's referring to an alert controller I've put in the app for when their subscription date is earlier than today's date) Then when I attempt to pay again it says in app purchase already made. Attempted at least 5 times. 
5. After each unsuccessful attempt to repurchase it just appears the app is in reloading mode. Has a thinking spinning wheel in middle of app  is best way to describe.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func buyOneMonthTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        activity.startAnimating()
        activity.isHidden = false


        product_ID = **(removed)**
        purchaseLength = "onemonth"

        print("About to fetch the products")

        // We check that we are allowed to make the purchase.


        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_ID!);
            let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            print("Fetching Products");

        }  else { print("can't make purchases")

            let cantPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Can't Make Purchases", message: "You do not have the ability to make purchases on this device. Please check your settings and payment info and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            cantPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.activity.isHidden = true
                self.activity.stopAnimating()
            }))


        }

    }


    @IBAction func buyOneYearTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        activity.startAnimating()
        activity.isHidden = false

        product_ID = **(removed)**
        purchaseLength = "oneyear"

        print("About to fetch the products")

        // We check that we are allowed to make the purchase.


        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_ID!);
            let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            print("Fetching Products");

        }  else { print("can't make purchases")

            let cantPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Can't Make Purchases", message: "You do not have the ability to make purchases on this device. Please check your settings and payment info and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            cantPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.activity.isHidden = true
                self.activity.stopAnimating()
            }))

        }

    }

    func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct){
        print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

    }

    func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        let count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {
            let validProducts = response.products
            let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_ID as String!) {
                print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                print(validProduct.localizedDescription)

                print(validProduct.price)
                buyProduct(validProduct);
            } else {
                print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            print("nothing")
        }
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error Fetching product information")

        let failedPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "We're sorry. There was an error with the purchase.", message: "Please quit the app and try again. If the error continues please email support@*****.com", preferredStyle: .alert)
        failedPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.activity.isHidden = true
            self.activity.stopAnimating()
        }))

        ;
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])    {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{


                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    print("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    subscriptionEndDate = userSettings.object(forKey: "subEnd") as? Date

                    let calendar = Calendar.current

                    let today = Date()

                    if purchaseLength == "onemonth" {

                        if (subscriptionEndDate as NSDate?)?.earlierDate(today) == today {

                            subscriptionEndDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: [.month], value: 1, to: subscriptionEndDate!, options: [])!

                        } else {

                            subscriptionEndDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: [.month], value: 1, to: today, options: [])!

                        } }

                    else  if purchaseLength == "oneyear" {

                        if (subscriptionEndDate as NSDate?)?.earlierDate(today) == today {

                            subscriptionEndDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: [.year], value: 1, to: subscriptionEndDate!, options: [])!

                        } else {

                            subscriptionEndDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: [.year], value: 1, to: today, options: [])!

                        }


                    }

                    print("added time")

                    let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.day, .month, .year], from: subscriptionEndDate!)

                    let year = components.year
                    let month = components.month
                    let day = components.day

                    let testDate = "\(month!)/\(day!)/\(year!)"


                    if (subscriptionEndDate! as NSDate).laterDate(today) == subscriptionEndDate {

                        subscriptionMessageLabel.text = "Your subscription expires on:"
                        subscriptionLabel.text = "\(testDate)" }


                    else {

                        subscriptionMessageLabel.text = "There was an error in the purchase."
                        subscriptionLabel.text = "Please contact Support@UndauntedAthlete.com" }

                    userSettings.set(subscriptionEndDate, forKey: "subEnd")


                    ref.updateChildValues(["users/\(userID!)/subscriptionDate": testDate])

                    activity.isHidden = true
                    activity.stopAnimating()

                    break;

                case .failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    let failedPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "We're sorry. There was an error with the purchase.", message: "Please quit the app and try again. If the error continues please email support@****.com", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    failedPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.activity.isHidden = true
                        self.activity.stopAnimating()
                    }))

                    break

                case .restored:
                    print("Already Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

                    let failedPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "We're sorry. There was an error with the purchase.", message: "Please quit the app and try again. If the error continues please email support@*****.com", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    failedPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.activity.isHidden = true
                        self.activity.stopAnimating()
                    }))

                default:
                    let failedPurchaseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "We're sorry. There was an error with the purchase.", message: "Please quit the app and try again. If the error continues please email support@*****.com", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    failedPurchaseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.activity.isHidden = true
                        self.activity.stopAnimating()
                    }))

                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Reviewing your code there are a lot of potential issues that could be causing client side bugs.

1. I would suggest prefetching the `SKProducts` before displaying the UI to the user. This allows you to display the price before they initiate a purchase, which is good UX in my opinion.
2. Because you are storing the state of what product was requested at the controller level, there could be bugs introduced if a user is able to dispatch two separate taps, i.e. taps monthly then annual in rapid succession before you are able to disable the UI. This would mess your code up.
3. You should be checking `canMakePayments` earlier, preventing the user from ever initiating a purchase.
4. I would remove the order dependency from `productRequest:didReceiveResponse:`. Don't just assume the 0th product is the one you are looking for, request all products and search for the one you want.
5. The biggest mis-implementation is the way you are calculating the expiration date. Apple provides the expiration date in the receipt info, this is the proper way to get the expiration for a subscription product. This means fetching the receipt data, sending it to Apple (or ideally your backend) for verification. The date that a transaction is processed by your transaction queue observer and its actual purchase date are not the same. Relying on the receipt for the expiration date removes the need for your app to do the tracking and expiration calculation, which is likely the source of this bug. Using the receipt for your subscription source of truth will be the best way to get your IAP code to match Apple's.

I realize "rewrite your IAP code" probably isn't the answer you were looking for but there is a lot of code here and its likely an issue in some interaction between `StoreKit` and your app. You should have a look at how [we do IAP at RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/index.html). It is a general implementation but it should give you an idea of how to properly interact with `StoreKit`.

Comment: Thank you! Your response was very, very helpful for understanding my code. I cleaned up the code using your response, found more resources, and rewrote everything. The root of the problem was that I never called finishTransaction(transaction) after the purchase so I had several purchases stuck in the queue. This response helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090901/clearing-skpaymentsqueue-forcing-unfinished-transactions-to-finish